# How to introduce network as a trusted source?

Tags: networking, visual-studio-2017, windows-10

In another post, I mentioned the problem of breakpoints not to be hit when debugging in VS2017. I mentioned that the breakpoints get hollow with an exclamation mark with the message:

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.
```

After some trial & effort, I found that it's because the sources are located on a network drive and when I copy the whole solution to C:, the problem gets resolved.
Now, I come with this problem that I need to hold the solution on the network drive and don't copy it to a local drive for resolving the problem. There, someone said that it's because the network is not introduced as a trusted source to Windows 10. It's weird that an EXE file can be executed from network and a PDB file can't be trusted!

Anyway, now I need to know how can I do it?